# HQL - Filtering data based on a particular field of a class in a one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I have one class "MasterUsers". This class has another class "Master" as a reference. The class "Master" has a one-to-many mapping to "Actions" class using List interface. "Actions" class is mapped to "ACTIONS" table and "MASTERUSERS" is mapped to "MASTERUSERS" table and "MASTER" is mapped to "MASTER" table.

My HQL looks like below :

StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer() ;
        hql.append("from MasterUsers where") ;

"ACTIONS" Table has a column called "actions_taken_id". I do not want to retrieve those data whose actions_id is 10.

What condition to be added here ?

Comment: You will have to make some join with the Master and Actions class and filter with that

Comment: HQL doesn't work with tables. It works with entities, their properties and their associations. So all your table description is useless, but the entities are required to answer the question. You should try something, though. Have you read the documentation of JPQL/HQL? If not, start with that.

Comment: Can you add your erd ? But i think you have to join beetwen your tables , your hibernate version also important , id you use 5.2 you can join them like sql